# php directoryIterator question - wrong path?

Tags: php, path, iterator, directory

hey guys,
what do I misunderstand here?

```
$dir = get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/headers/';
echo $dir;
//ouput: myblog.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/headers



$dir = new DirectoryIterator(get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/headers/');
echo $dir;
//output: nothing at all! blank page!
```

the console puts out a fatal_error:

> [26-Apr-2011] PHP Fatal error: 
>   Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException'
>   with message
>   'DirectoryIterator::__construct(http://myblog.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/headers/)
>   [directoryiterator.--construct]:
>   failed to open dir: not implemented'
>   in
>   /Users/myname/htdocs/myblog.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/header-image.php:3
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /Users/myname/htdocs/myblog.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/header-image.php(3):
>
> DirectoryIterator->__construct('http://oberperf...')
>
> ## 1 /Users/myname/htdocs/myblog.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/header.php(69):
>
> include('/Users/myname...')
>
> ## 2 /Users/myname/htdocs/myblog.com/wp-includes/theme.php(1112):
>
> require_once('/Users/myname...')
>
> ## 3 /Users/myname/htdocs/myblog.com/wp-includes/theme.php(1088):
>
> load_template('/Users/myname...',
>   true)
>
> ## 4 /Users/myname/htdocs/myblog.com/wp-includes/general-template.php(34):
>
> locate_template(Array, true)
>
> ## 5 /Users/myname in /Users/myname/htdocs/myblog.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/header-image.php
>
> on line 3

any idea what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the path must be absolute from the document root, not a URL.

Try [`get_template_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) instead:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator( get_template_directory() . '/images/headers/');
echo $dir;
```

Comment: thank you, that makes sense. However it doesn't work! If I try your exact code $dir holds just a "." dot! no path in there. No errors are thrown. If I echo `get_template_directory() . '/images/headers/'` it works fine, however DirectoryIterator won't take that value for some reason!

Comment: the variable returned by the DirectoryIterator constructor is a DirectoryIterator OBJECT, you won't be able to just echo it to the screen. take a look at the DirectoryIterator documentation for more info on how to use it http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're passing a URL instead of a path:

```
DirectoryIterator->__construct('http://oberperf...')
```

You should pass the full local path name of the directory to the constructor.

Comment: ok, that's true. However that doesn't work either: `$dir = new DirectoryIterator('/Users/myname/htdocs/myblog.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/headers/');
echo $dir;` <- this puts out just a "." dot!

Comment: DirectoryIterator returns an object not a string. You need to iterate over it: foreach ($dir as $item) { echo $item->getFilename(); }